# Opening PDF file in zip without extracting, using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, zip

I was wondering if it is possible to open a PDF file that is located in a .zip file without extracting the .zip file? I am able to open the PDF if it's not in a .zip file, like this:

```
<?
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=C:\orders\data.pdf");
@readfile("filename=C:\orders\data.pdf");
?>
```

I tried to do it like this, but this doesn't work:

```
<?
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=C:\orders\datacollection.zip\data.pdf");
@readfile("filename=C:\orders\datacollection.zip\data.pdf");
?>
```

So my question is, is it possible with PHP to open a PDF file that is located in a .zip file without extracting it?

I also tried this but it didn't help:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('weborder.zip');
$contents = $z->getFromName('weborder.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `@`. Ever. 2. http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php

Comment: Why not? It seems to work?

Comment: Yeah error suppression is great! Until your code stops working and you have no idea why because you've suppressed all of the error messages that might otherwise help you diagnose the problem. Use `error_reporting` to control the visibility of errors, don't suppress them like this.

Comment: (I've made a couple of edits to tidy up - there's many presentation memes 'round here, but basically I've removed the salutations/signature, and moved the answer edit to an answer proper, so the Q&A separation is maintained. You are welcome to do this yourself in future, and it may even earn you reputation points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [zip://](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) wrapper:

You can use it with `fopen/fread` or just `file_get_contents`:

```
$pdf = file_get_contents('zip://datacollection.zip#data.pdf');
echo $pdf;
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get the following result: http://gyazo.com/b2420649a49f127b2599f3f4378c2645

Comment: You still have the `content-type` header set? Looks like PDF data, but the browser doesn't know it's PDF.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of OP):*

Here is a solution, thanks to JoeCoder:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
$pdf = file_get_contents('zip://C:/xampp/htdocs/weborder.zip#weborder.pdf');
echo $pdf;
?>
```